# RequireJs text plugin gives Cross origin error in Chrome

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have some very basic RequireJs code that fetches an html file with simple html.
In Firefox 8.0 it works fine, however in my build of Chrome (17.0.9.xxx) I get the following error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Could this just be a problem with this build of Chrome or the text plugin in general?

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'backbone', 
    'text!templates/home/listOfStuff.html'
    ], function ($, Backbone, mainTemplate) {
        var mainView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#list'),
            render: function () { 
                this.el.html(mainTemplate);
            }

        });


        // return the view object
        return new mainView;

});
```

When Require attempts to fetch the html file is when the error occurs.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues here and I have a fairly large project with multiple text! plugin uses. Chrome 17.0.943.0 (Chrome Canary as of today)

Comment: Look in your chrome console and try to find the xhttp request. Which url is chrome trying to fetch the html file from?

Comment: @ProTom file:///C:/Users/xxx/xxx/Projects/RequireJs/templates/home/listOfStuff.html That is the location of the html file I'm trying to pull in.

Comment: So the problem is that you are running your application from the filesystem instead of a webserver. XHR request do not work from the filesystem in some browsers. You have to start some http server like Apache (or node.js or something) and run your application via the server. Your code should work in any browser then.

Comment: Thats weird that it would work in firefox though right? And I found another example and it works fine. But yes running it in a server of some kind works...

Comment: It is indeed weired, and more so as every browser handles this differently. In some you get a dialog asking you for permission, in some it just works and in some (like chrome obviously) it just does not. If I run something on my local machine with my permissions I just would expect it to run anyhow. Weird indeed!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with ProTom there, if you set up a webserver to serve up your html pages you should be all set.

Answer (score 9):

It's chrome's local file system access policy. For local development you could just add following flags:

> --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security

Comment: When I added this argument `--disable-web-security`, chrome gave me this warning '...Stability and security will suffer'. Wondering if that's going to harm my system in any way.

Comment: where/how do you add these?

Comment: @natecraft1 You can execute chrome from cmd with the arugments.
[link](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/)